# Triangle rendering as rectangle CSS due to mistake

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner with CSS and HTML and currently I'm trying to create a triangle with CSS styling. I've looked up how to do it online and the common wisdom seems to be with borders. I've tried using the examples I've seen but I just get a rectangle.

```css
html,
body {
    background-color: #DBDCDE;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    /*white-space: nowrap;*/
    position: relative;
}

.shape {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
    top: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid blanchedalmond;
}

.blanchedalmond {
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    left: -400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape triangle blanchedalmond"></div>
```

I just get a rectangle on screen:

[rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hygdh.png)

(using Chrome to test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #DBDCDE;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  /*white-space: nowrap;*/
  position: relative;
}

.shape {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid blanchedalmond;
}

.blanchedalmond {
  left: -300px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape triangle blanchedalmond"></div>
```

Removed `background-color` from `.blanchedalmond`.